# UILabel in UITableView setting size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel

I would like to add a label subview to a UITableViewCell. I can easily set the frame origin and size myself to specific values but how can I use the current/default cell label height and position?

```
  UILabel *labPerHour;

  cell.textLabel.text       = @"Rate";

  labPerHour = [[UILabel alloc] init];

  //labPerHour.frame = CGRectMake( 280, cell.textLabel.frame.origin.y, 80, cell.textLabel.frame.size.height );
  labPerHour.frame = CGRectMake( 260, 7, 30, 30 );
  labPerHour.text  = @"$/hr";


  [cell addSubview:labPerHour];
```

I would like the commented-out line to work.. or something similar.

Can somebody please help? This code is of course part of my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Have you created prototype cell using ios5 storyboard feature?

Comment: No, I'm still using Xcode 4. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure. May be it will work. I haven't tried this before!!

```
CGRect theFrame = cell.textLabel.frame;
theFrame.origin.x = 280;
theFrame.size.width = 80;
labPerHour.frame = theFrame;
```

Comment: Well that would and also (potentially) change the size of cell.textLabel to the specific sizes you've quoted above.. What I am after is the default cell.textLabel sizes - whatever iOS assigns to them initially.

Comment: What was the output you got for this?? It is similar to what you had tried in your code!!

    labPerHour.frame = CGRectMake( 280, cell.textLabel.frame.origin.y, 80, cell.textLabel.frame.size.height );


Isn't it??

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to get the frame of default label of uitable view, then you may try this

```
CGRect myframe;
myframe= cell.textlabel.frame;
```

now use this as per need

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide coordinates relative to the superview’s coordinate system. These coordinates need to make sense, so your label is still positioned inside your cell's frame, not outside it.

> Because every view and window defines its own local coordinate system,
>   you need to be aware of which coordinate system is in effect at any
>   given time. Every time you draw into a view or change its geometry,
>   you do so relative to some coordinate system. In the case of drawing,
>   you specify coordinates relative to the view’s own coordinate system.
>   In the case of geometry changes, you specify coordinates relative to
>   the superview’s coordinate system. The UIWindow and UIView classes
>   both include methods to help you convert from one coordinate system to
>   another.

Section "View Geometry and Coordinate Systems" of [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your cell label frame initially.

```
cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 10);
```

Comment: But surely it has a frame already? My cell and text label already have a default size which I don't want to change - I just want to make use of that default size so my additional subview labels are the same size as the default label in the cell. If I had my Mac with me I'd print out the contents of cell.textLabel.frame but will have to wait until I can get back to my Mac..

Comment: ya its already have frame...and i tried to get frame according to your requirement , but i was getting cell textlabel frame size after scrolling the table...means in starting , when table load..i was getting cell text label height = 0, and after first scrolliung i was getting actual textlabel size...;

Comment: so you have to scroll the table first to get your textLabel size or u have to provide textLabel frame size initially..

Comment: I understand what you are saying. The other answers would suggest that the normal way of doing this is to specify an actual size first.. I honestly would have thought that there would have been a simpler way of determining/predicting what iOS is going to use.. but perhaps there is not.